# Re-assigning / changing the Primary Log File - SQL 2000

Tags: log-files, sql-server

I've got a large db (called Navision4) which currently has 2 log files:

Navision4_Log
Navision4_Log3

There *was* a log called Navision4_Log2, but i managed to remove this.

Navision4_Log is located on the C:\ drive - and is not used.
Navision4_Log3 is located on the G:\ drive - but is huge - and this appears to be where all transactions are written.

However, I want to remove one, leaving just one log file.

How should I do this? I tried to remove Navision4_Log - but got:

> Error 5020: The primary data or log
>   file cannot be removed from a database

Answer (score 1):

What recovery model is your database using?  are you taking regular log backups?  If your in full recovery & not taking log backups, then this may explain why Navision4_Log3 is so large. You should fix this by either taking log backups, or switch to simple recovery.

I would move Navision4_Log to the G drive rather then try to remove it.  My guess is that Navision4_Log3 exists because the server was running out of space on C: & the admin didn't know how to move it.

To move the log file to G: use the following:

<strike>ALTER DATABASE Navision4 SET OFFLINE;

    --move log file to G:

    ALTER DATABASE Navision4

          MODIFY FILE (

                NAME='Navision4_Log',

                FILENAME='G:\MSSQL\TLOG\Navision4_Log.ldf');

    ALTER DATABASE Navision4 SET ONLINE;</strike> 

**EDIT:**SQL Server 2000 doesn't support those options, so you'll have to use sp_detachdb & sp_attachdb, you can also detach & attach in the Enterprise Manager GUI.  Just make sure you attach the db & specify the owner as sa.

Then you can remove Navision4_Log3 if you wish.  What you'll need to do (if your in full recovery) is take a log backup, then shrink the log using `DBCC SHRINKFILE('Navision4_Log3', EMPTYFILE)` 
You may need to take several backups & do several shrinks before the file will empty out & then you should be able to remove it.

Comment: Thanks for this excellent answer...
This DB is also a replication publisher - does this affect me detaching / re-attaching?

Comment: no it shouldn't

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a replicated database, you will have to remove replication before detaching. SQL Server 2000 will not allow you to detach a replicated database.

After that Nick is correct, detach the database and reattach with only the only file you wish to use on the G: